# Using diff on a SymPy Function object returns 1

Tags: python, sympy

I set up an undefined function and a variable to go with it:

```
import sympy as sp

f = sp.Function('f')
t = sp.Symbol('t')
```

If I differentiate `f(t)` with respect to `t`, it works fine:

```
f(t).diff(t)
# Derivative(f(t), t)
```

However, if I differentiate `f` itself with respect to `t`, I get this:

```
f.diff(t)
# 1
```

I'm not exactly sure what I expected here (probably an error), but I certainly didn't expect 1. What's going on?

Answer (score 1):

A SymPy Function object is actually a Python class:

```
In [15]: f = Function('f')

In [16]: type(f(t))
Out[16]: f

In [17]: isinstance(f(t), f)
Out[17]: True
```

This is analogous to `cos(t)` being an instance of the `cos` class. Consequently `f.diff` is equivalent to `Expr.diff` i.e. an unbound class method:

```
In [18]: f.diff
Out[18]: <function sympy.core.expr.Expr.diff(self, *symbols, **assumptions)>

In [19]: Expr.diff
Out[19]: <function sympy.core.expr.Expr.diff(self, *symbols, **assumptions)>

In [20]: Expr.diff(t)
Out[20]: 1
```

This is equivalent to:

```
In [21]: t.diff()
Out[21]: 1
```

Note that the diff method allows not specifying the differentiation variable if the expression only has one symbol:

```
In [22]: sin(t).diff(t)
Out[22]: cos(t)

In [23]: sin(t).diff()
Out[23]: cos(t)
```